# Variable in my python script is not being set

Tags: python

I have a python script that uses the pyzabbix module for querying the API of Zabbix.  I have a text file with hostnames that I want to loop through the script but the hosts variable is not being set.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI, ZabbixAPIException
import sys

# The hostname at which the Zabbix web interface is available
ZABBIX_SERVER = 'https://zabbix.example.org'

zapi = ZabbixAPI(ZABBIX_SERVER)
zapi.session.verify = False

# Login to the Zabbix API
zapi.login('Admin', 'password')

infile = open("data.txt", "r")
for line in infile:
    host_name = line
    hosts = zapi.host.get(filter={"host": host_name}, selectInterfaces=["interfaceid"]) 
    if hosts:
        host_id = hosts[0]["hostid"]
        print("Found host id {0}".format(host_id))
    else:
        print("No hosts found")

infile.close()
```

Comment: Print `line` before setting the `host`, add log or output to make it more clear

Comment: Once you've opened your file, you will need to read it into memory and slplit it into lines. So something like `content = open("data.txt", "r").read()`  and `for line in content.spitlines()`

Comment: Adding those worked!  Just had to add : to the end of ```for line in infile.splitlines():```